External IP of a service in Openshift
I have a problem when requesting my External IP of my service in OpenShift, after patching the service it remains in "pending" state and it does not show me the url in the console after requesting it through this command
$argoURL = oc get svc argocd-server -n argocdju -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'

I hope you can help me soon please thank you all
I already deleted the service, created it again, stopped patching it, looked for it manually in the searched files and nothing
